# RxJava newbee problems in thread order execution

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

Good evening guys, I'm new in RxJava and in functional programming at all. So i have Retrofit repo with a method:

```
 @POST("/rest/getMonitors")
Observable<List<Camera>> getMonitors(@Body User user);
```

which is working correctly. It returns me List of my Camera entities.

In my MainActivity:

```
List<Camera> cameraList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    serverApi.getMonitors(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    cameras -> cameraList = cameras,
                    throwable -> {},
                    ()->onStart()
                    );
 }
```

So in OnCreate I'm trying to get List of cameras. In onNext method I'm saving cameras in local field and onComplete method i'm calling for onStart.

But when I call:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("@@@SIZE", String.valueOf(cameraList.size()));}
```

It gives me:

```
'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

Could you explain the problem, please. Much appreciate for help.

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to ever call android lifecycle methods directly. I think what's most likely here is that the android framework is calling onStart() automatically before your network call has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `protected void onStart()` is a lifecycle method of your `Activity` that is called after `Activity` gets visible. But at that point your `onComplete` hasn't been called yet and so the `cameraList` is still `null`. Hence, print the content in the some non-lifecycle method (create one if needed) or right in `onComplete`.

As @Ben P pointed out it's a bad idea to call lifecycle methods directly. In this case  you meddle with normal sequence of lifecycle calls that may lead to the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: So my onComplete doesn't keep up for onStart?

Comment: @NickKyrpenko yep, your `onComplete` is called after `ònStart`. As  @Ben P pointed out it's a bad idea to use lifecycle methods like this.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have `NPE` because you forgot that getting cameras from retrofit is **asynchronous** operation. It means that it will be done not when you call it, but after some time.

So what you have

1. You called `onCreate`
2. Async operation started, you requested for list
3. You use that list in `onStart`, but list **doesnt exist** yet
4. Async operation ended, list is now available.

In other words you cant use it until RxJava's `subscribe` method is called.

Do not call `onStart()` manually, its system callback after all and runs automatically when screen is visible to user. It happens **much earlier** than you call it manually.

Comment: Can I make it synchronous if I need my cameraList available in onStart method or it doesn't make sence to using Rx and just make OkHttpRequest?

Comment: @NickKyrpenko, nope, you cant. You should call in subscribe another method, not onStart.